# joi validation : field required depending of ohers fields

Tags: node.js, joi

I am using joi validation in a node project. I have the following need :

I receive an object with the following keys :

- a
- b
- c
- d

All the keys are not required together, but only valid object is if :

- only a and b keys are defined
- only c and d keys are defined

every other case should be invalid

Exemple of valid objects :

```
{
  a:'',
  b:''
}

{
  c:'',
  d:''
}
```

Exemple of invalid objects :

```
{
  a:'',
  b:'',
  c:'',
}

{
  a:''
}

{
}

...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Joi version **17.2.1**

I know of two options on how to do this:

Option `1`

```js
const joi = require('joi');

const schema = joi.object().keys({
  a: joi.string(),
  b: joi.string(),
  c: joi.string(),
  d: joi.string(),
})
.xor('a', 'c')
.xor('a', 'd')
.xor('b', 'c')
.xor('b', 'd')
.required();
```

Option `2`

```js
const joi = require('joi');

const schema = joi.alternatives().try(
  joi.object({
    a: joi.string().required(),
    b: joi.string().required()
  }),
  joi.object({
    c: joi.string().required(),
    d: joi.string().required(),
  })
);
```

Run some tests:

```js
// should work
const aAndB = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
};
console.log(schema.validate(aAndB).error);

// should work
const cAndD = {
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
};
console.log(schema.validate(cAndD).error);


// should not work
const aAndC = {
  a: 'a',
  c: 'c'
};
console.log(schema.validate(aAndC).error);


// should not work
const onlyA = {
  a: 'a',
};
console.log(schema.validate(onlyA).error);

// should not work
const onlyB = {
  b: 'b',
};
console.log(schema.validate(onlyB).error);

// should not work
const onlyC = {
  c: 'c',
};
console.log(schema.validate(onlyC).error);

// should not work
const onlyD = {
  d: 'd',
};
console.log(schema.validate(onlyD).error);
```

Comment: this answer was very usefull for me, thank you.